# What is the opposite of the word 'smelly' for the following context?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, antonyms

> XXX fertilizer is an organic degradation that can produce **non-smelly** waste and increase the plant growth.

Is "non-smelly" appropriate?

Answer (score 9):

If you mean that the waste has no smell at all, then you can use the word ***odorless***.

If you mean that the waste doesn't have a rank smell, then you can use something like ***pleasant-smelling*** – if it has an odor that is pleasant. Otherwise, you might have to explain what you mean another way:

> XXX fertilizer is an organic degradation that can increase the plant growth **without producing the unpleasant smells** of other organic waste.

Answer (score 2):

"Non-smelly" is a bit awkward and not very specific, but it could be used.

However, "odorless" works better here, to signify not that it smells good (which is not usually particularly desirable), but that it doesn't smell much at all.

Comment: odorless would mean doesn't have any smell at all, while I think the OP means the smell is just not-bad

Answer (score 1):

How about "that can produce **neutral smelling** waste"?
Neutral would signify it doesn't smell unpleasant or pleasant. Just that it isn't odorless and the smell is pretty neutral smelling.

Comment: I'd write it with a hypen in between (i.e., neutral-smelling waste).

Answer (score 0):

**odor-free** is commonly used in marketing material.